# Usage of api key bundle for Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I've successfully installed and configured this bundle (I think so) [Api Key Bundle](https://github.com/uecode/api-key-bundle)
and now I want to figure out how to use it. I've added this provider to my security.yml:

```
          auth:
          pattern: ^/api/*
          api_key: true
          stateless: true
```

Shall I change routing for my api to something like that:

```
acme_api_user_data:
resource: "@AcmeEventManagerBundle/Controller/ApiController/UserDataController.php"
prefix: /api/{api_key}/v1/
type: rest
```

and after login save api_key to cookie to use it in further queries?

Comment: Please clarify what the problem is.

Comment: I don't know (newbie here) how should I utilize api key generated by that bundle for authorization purposes at my web service. Should I  modify my routings and insert it as a parameter and pass it in each query to API (API key saved as a cookie after login action)

Comment: Hi @michalSolarz, did you find any answer on this after so much time ? :)